# How to get then append content of SQL script file to shell script?

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, docker, shell

I am using Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629) for Windows (use Windows Sub-Linux), Windows 11 pro x64. Folder structure

[image]

For a DevOps task, I have file `D:\github\spring_jwt\vy_notes\database_postgres_part_001_100.sql` (1) has content

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tenant;
CREATE TABLE tenant
(
    id               smallint primary key,
    company_tax_code character varying(14),
    period           character varying(16), -- 2021070420220705
    created          timestamp with time zone
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_id_tenant()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    new.id = (select coalesce(max(id), -32769) from tenant) + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_without_id_tenant
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON tenant
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id_tenant();

CREATE INDEX tenant_idx ON tenant (id);
COMMIT;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 1.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;
CREATE TABLE account
(
    id                              smallint,
    account_number                  character varying(32)  not null unique,
    account_name                    character varying(128) not null,
    account_name_english            character varying(128),
    account_name_chinese            character varying(128),
    account_name_korean             character varying(128),
    description                     character varying(512),
    parent_id                       smallint,
    internal_code_id                character varying(128),
    grade                           smallint,
    is_parent                       boolean                not null,
    account_category_kind           smallint               not null,
    is_postable_in_foreign_currency boolean                not null,
    detail_by_account_object        boolean                not null,
    account_object_type             smallint,
    detail_by_bank_account          boolean                not null,
    detail_by_job                   boolean                not null,
    detail_by_job_kind              smallint,
    detail_by_project_work          boolean                not null,
    detail_by_project_work_kind     smallint,
    detail_by_order                 boolean                not null,
    detail_by_order_kind            smallint,
    detail_by_contract              boolean                not null,
    detail_by_contract_kind         smallint,
    detail_by_expense_item          boolean                not null,
    detail_by_expense_item_kind     smallint,
    detail_by_department            boolean                not null,
    detail_by_department_kind       smallint,
    detail_by_list_item             boolean                not null,
    detail_by_list_item_kind        smallint,
    active_status                   boolean                not null,
    created                         timestamp with time zone,
    created_by                      character varying(64),
    modified                        timestamp with time zone,
    modified_by                     character varying(64),
    sort_internal_code_id           character varying(128),
    detail_by_pu_contract           boolean                not null,
    detail_by_pu_contract_kind      smallint,
    tenant_id                       smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id) -- ,
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_tenant FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_setId()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    new.id = (select coalesce(max(id), -32769) from account where tenant_id = new.tenant_id) + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER account_trig_insertWithoutId
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON account
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_setId();

CREATE INDEX account_idx ON account (id, tenant_id);

COMMENT ON TABLE public.account IS 'Danh mục tài khoản';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.id IS 'PK Tài khoản';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_number IS 'Số hiệu tài khoản';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_name IS 'Tên tài khoản';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_name_english IS 'Tên tài khoản bằng Tiếng Anh';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_name_chinese IS 'Tên tài khoản bằng Tiếng Trung';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_name_korean IS 'Tên tài khoản bằng Tiếng Hàn Quốc';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.description IS 'Diễn giải';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.parent_id IS 'TK Tổng hợp';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.grade IS 'Cấp bậc';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.is_parent IS 'Là TK tổng hợp';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_category_kind IS 'Tính chất tài khoản: 0: Dư nợ; 1: Dư có; 2: Lưỡng tính';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.is_postable_in_foreign_currency IS 'Có hạch toán ngoại tệ';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_account_object IS 'Chi tiết theo đối tượng';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.account_object_type IS 'Loại đối tượng: 0 - Nhà cung cấp, 1- Khách hàng, 2- Nhân viên';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_bank_account IS 'Chi tiết theo tài khoản ngân hàng';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_job IS 'Chi tiết theo đối tượng tập hợp chi phí';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_job_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_project_work IS 'Chi tiết theo công trình, vụ việc';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_project_work_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_order IS 'Chi tiết theo đơn hàng';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_order_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_contract IS 'Chi tiết theo hợp đồng';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_contract_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_expense_item IS 'Chi tiết theo Khoản mục CP';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_expense_item_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_department IS 'Chi tiết theo đơn vị';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_department_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_list_item IS 'Chi tiết theo mã thống kê';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.detail_by_list_item_kind IS '0 = Chỉ cảnh báo; 1 = Bắt buộc nhập';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.active_status IS 'Trạng thái theo dõi';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account.sort_internal_code_id IS 'Cột dùng để sort trên báo cáo. Không sử dụng trên giao diện.';

COMMIT;
```

I have file `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres-14
#    image: postgres:latest
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./create-databases.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-databases.sh
      - ./db_persist:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=tenant_single_db
    hostname: postgres
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.12
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@example.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=123456a@
    hostname: pgadmin

# docker compose up
# pgAdmin: http://localhost:8080/
```

I have file `D:\github\spring_jwt\create-databases.sh` (2) has content

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

function create_database() {
  local database=$1
  echo "  Creating database '$database'"
  psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE $database;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $POSTGRES_USER;
    
EOSQL
}
```

How to append content of to (1) to a position what stand before `EOSQL` in file (2)?

Comment: I would use psql to execute the whole sql file, after EOSQL `psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $database -f database_postgres_part_001_100.sql` - you'll need to have the full path to the SQL file.

Comment: It did not work. https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/091b114fd3b937bf2a1ede59c93576d3 and https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/0fca19e08708a40d4f987ecca159b658